# Jolt to Map input fields with conditions

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to make some jolt where I need to map only one input to output.

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

- If **topicA.owner** and **topicZ.owner** both present output owner.name should be mapped to **topicZ.owner**
- if **topicA.owner** only then output owner.name should be mapped to **topicA.owner**
- if **topicZ.owner** only then output owner.name should be mapped to **topicZ.owner**

Input :

```
{
  "topicA": {
    "owner": "topic_a_owner"
  },
  "topicZ": {
    "owner": "topic_z_owner"
  }
}
```

Jolt:

```
[
  {
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ta": "@(2,topicA.owner)",
        "za": "@(2,topicZ.owner)"
      }
    },
    "operation": "modify-default-beta"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "topicA": {
        "ta": "owner.name"
      },
      "topicZ": {
        "za": "owner.name"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "owner" : {
    "name" : "topic_z_owner"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 3 conditions you have mentioned can be simplified into 2 conditions as below.

- If **topicZ.owner** presents, (irrespective of whether **topicA.owner** is present or not) then output **owner.name** should be mapped to **topicZ.owner** (This merges your 1st and 3rd conditions)
- If **topicA.owner** only presents, then output **owner.name** should be mapped to **topicA.owner**

So based on this, you can do the following operations.

1. Use `modify-default-beta` operation to copy the value of `topicA.owner` to `topicZ.owner` field **when `topicZ.owner` is not present**.
2. Use `shift` operation to map the value of `topicZ.owner` to `owner.name` field on the output.

```
[
  {
    "spec": {
      "topicZ": {
        "owner": "@(2,topicA.owner)"
      }
    },
    "operation": "modify-default-beta"
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "topicZ": {
        "owner": "owner.name"
      }
    }
  }
]
```